# Why i am getting NullPointerException when i run this code

Tags: nullpointerexception

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3Kys.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DmbHL.png)

here i am trying to catch the name of wickettaker and batsman and i have created xpath which is showing 1 of 1 even if its throw the NullPointerException. i have done debigging and its showing that driver is null.i have looked up what is it but still i dont understand how to fix it.can anyone help please?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.